# DataTables auto dynamic column width

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable being populated by json data via ajax. I have the autoWidth property set to false. What I am looking to do is set certain columns to have a width based on the content that is returned.

What it looks like is happening during pagination is that the table is being redrawn or something every page I go to. This is causing the columns to bounce around in different positions and/or changing the width of that column. I can't seem to find what I need to do.

What I am looking for is once the table is loaded with data the first time each column min-width is set to the largest data content returned in that row. I hope I am explaining that correctly. What I ultimately want is the columns to not adjust widths after the data is loaded the first time. So not on pagination or sorting of columns.

The only thing I did try was table.columns.adjust().draw(); but I put in the the drawCallback function as I didn't know where else to do it. That didn't seem to do anything for me.

I have googled for long enough of this and was hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction or provide a little help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good way of doing this using DataTables itself, since the column widths have to be declared upon initialization.

However, you can do something pretty similar using vanilla JavaScript and CSS after everything has loaded:

```
    // get the table headers into an array
    let tableHeaders = document.querySelectorAll("#YOUR-TABLE-ID thead th");

    tableHeaders.forEach((element) => {
        // get the computed width for the column
        const computedWidth = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("width");
        // set CSS min-width on element
        element.style.minWidth = computedWidth;
    });
```

Widths will automatically be applied to all `<td>` elements within the same column as a `<th>` element that has width styles.

Also be aware that DataTables assigns a `width` style property to each `<th>` element.

Comment: This is close to what I need. Though I am not fully understanding how this works. This is getting the width of each cell? Then setting the minWIdth. What I need is to figure out each columns cell that is the largest and set that as the minWidth

Comment: The `computedWidth` var gets the width of each column as it is rendered by the browser and then sets that as `min-width`.  Are you trying to keep the columns from wrapping onto two lines or something like that? I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: No. When the data table is first displayed I just want to keep the width of the columns as they are. What is happening is if you sort or paginate other columns move from the child rows of the responsive table into the visible area and vice versa. So if I sort say on a persons name that column will sometimes get wider or shorter and the other columns "bounce" around or get added/removed from the table. The table displays thousands of rows sometimes and it can be hard to follow what is going on in each row as things appear and disappear.

Comment: Is there some reason that applying fixed widths to the columns won't work for your needs? That would be the normal way of going about it. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width